# Native CheckedListBox?

Tags: c++, c, windows

In .NET land, there's the tremendously useful [System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) class.

What is the equivalent in Windows Common Controls land? (if any)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn a list view into one with checkboxes. If you want it similar to a ListBox, only use 1 column.

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle (handle, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical UI can be developed with the List View control by using item state images.

But selection management and other functionalities need to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/Win32SDK_ListboxCombobox.aspx) article might be of interest for you. In short windows allows quite easily to implement checkboxes in Listbox and combobox through custom drawing and messaging.